# Firebase query the application crashes when opening

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

The application crashes when opening.

I've been interested in technology for a while. I'm working on a project. I want to list the data as I want. But I'm having some problems.

logcat : 
`05-07 23:53:43.588 18182-18182/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.erdemswordx.eticaretuygulama.menuapplicaion, PID: 18182
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/QueryListenOptions;
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions$Builder.setQuery(FirestoreRecyclerOptions.java:108)
        at com.erdemswordx.eticaretuygulama.menuapplicaion.MainScreen.Fragments.UrunlerFragment.onStart(UrunlerFragment.java:199)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2477)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1494)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3235)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:212)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:628)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1288)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6279)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryListenOptions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.erdemswordx.eticaretuygulama.menuapplicaion-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.erdemswordx.eticaretuygulama.menuapplicaion-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib/egl, system/lib/hw]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions$Builder.setQuery(FirestoreRecyclerOptions.java:108) 
        at com.erdemswordx.eticaretuygulama.menuapplicaion.MainScreen.Fragments.UrunlerFragment.onStart(UrunlerFragment.java:199) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2477) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1494) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3235) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:212) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:628) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1288) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6279) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryListenOptions
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 24 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
05-07 23:53:43.588 1808-1818/? E/ActivityManager: App crashed! Process: com.erdemswordx.eticaretuygulama.menuapplicaion`

Thanks for help.

gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
```

}

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String searchText = searchField.getText().toString();
    Query query = dbRef.orderBy("aracParkSaati",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
    try {
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<OtoparkAraclar> options =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<OtoparkAraclar>()
                        .setQuery(query, OtoparkAraclar.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<OtoparkAraclar, RequestViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(RequestViewHolder holder, int position, OtoparkAraclar model) {
                final String arac_id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();
                final String plaka = String.valueOf(model.getPlakaText());
                final String adsoyad = String.valueOf(model.getAdsoyadText());
                final String aractipi = String.valueOf(model.getAracTipiText());
                final String aracrengi = String.valueOf(model.getAracRengiText());
                final String tcno = String.valueOf(model.getTcnoText());
                final String telefon = String.valueOf(model.getTelefonText());
                final long girisZaman = Long.valueOf(model.getAracGirisTarihiText());
                final String girisZaman1 = getDate(girisZaman, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                final long cikisZaman = Long.valueOf(model.getAracParkSaati());
                final String cikisZaman1 = getDate(cikisZaman, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                holder.aracPlakaLayout.setText(model.getPlakaText());
                holder.girisTarihiLayout.setText("Giriş tarihi : " + girisZaman1);
                holder.cikisTarihiLayout.setText("Çıkış tarihi : " + cikisZaman1);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent aracDetailActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), AracDetails.class);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("arac_id", arac_id);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("adsoyad", adsoyad);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("plaka", plaka);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("aractipi", aractipi);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("aracrengi", aracrengi);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("tcno", tcno);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("telefon", telefon);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("giris", girisZaman1);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("cikis", cikisZaman1);
                        aracDetailActivity.putExtra("timeago", girisZaman);
                        startActivity(aracDetailActivity);
                    }
                });
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
                layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public RequestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout, viewGroup, false);
                RequestViewHolder holder = new RequestViewHolder(view);
                return holder;
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Hata!" + ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
```

}

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could post the relevant errors, that I assume you're getting when/before your code crashes.

Comment: This code works in realtime database. But not working on cloud firestore. I can't see errors for trying on my phone.

Comment: ı shared my logcat. Anyone help me?

Comment: I solved my problem. this video was very helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAGI6jGS4vs